# java regex to ignore the domain name in a URL and consider everything beyond

Tags: java, regex

Here is my case:

I need everything beyond the domain name in the URL, i.e, everything beyond the third occurence of /
Here is the sample URL:
https://test-qa-documents.ss-us-abc-2.mentor.com/thumbnail/58043233791488_testfit_image?X-Amz-Security-Token=xyz

I need the output as: 
thumbnail/58043233791488_testfit_image?X-Amz-Security-Token=xyz

Any help on this?

Comment: Do you have any code?  I don't think this is a homework question, but you should still try to show us some effort.

Comment: Quick hint. You don't need regular expressions. The protocol will contain two forward slashes. The content you are looking for is after the third. That is, if you bother parsing your URL as a `String` (e.g. for some homework exercise). Lucky for you, Java provides a [java.net.URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class with methods to retrieve its parts.

Answer (score 1):

The Java [`URL class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) has support many types of parsing URLs.  In this case, you can use `URL#getFile()` on your URL to obtain the string portion you want.

```
// import java.net.*
String url = "https://test-qa-documents.ss-us-abc-2.mentor.com/thumbnail/58043233791488_testfit_image?X-Amz-Security-Token=xyz";
URL theURL = new URL(url);
System.out.println(theURL.getFile());
```

**Output:**

```
/thumbnail/58043233791488_testfit_image?X-Amz-Security-Token=xyz
```

Comment: Thanks for this simple solution.. It worked perfectly fine.

Comment: I had tried various regex combinations before this.. Sorry about not posting them along with my question.

Answer (score 0):

url.replaceFirst("https?://[^/]+/","")

Just replace `http://.../` part to blank.